# Alterar um registro com um WebService REST

Tags: java, delphi, web-service

Estou tentando fazer alterar o registro do meu banco através de um webservice rest em java, os teste no webservice funcionaram, mas no client estou tendo problema para funcionar.

Obs.: Utilizo Delphi XE8(Client) e Netbeans(WS)

WS:

```
@PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path ("Banco/put/{codigo}")
    public String putBanco(@PathParam("codigo") int codigo, String nome) {

        BancoCTR ctr = new BancoCTR();
        ctr.setBcoNome(nome);

        BancoDAO dao = new BancoDAO();
        String resposta = dao.editBanco(codigo, ctr);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(resposta);
    }
```

Quando faço o teste direto, esta funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém estou com uma duvida, `public String putBanco(@PathParam("codigo") int código, String nome)` o PathParam faz com que eu tenha acesso a essa variável "código", porém como eu terei acesso a variavel "nome" no client?

Client:

```
procedure TForm1.btn2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LJson: TJSONValue;
begin
  rstrspns1.RootElement := 'object';

  with rstrqst1 do
  begin

    Resource := '/Banco/put/{codigo}';
    Method := rmPUT;

    Params.AddUrlSegment('codigo', edt1.Text);
    Params.AddItem('nome', edt2.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);
    Execute;

    LJson := Response.JSONValue As TJSONObject;

    MessageDlg(LJson.ToString, mtInformation, [mbOK], 0);
  end;
end;
```

pensei em utilizar `Params.AddItem('nome', edt2.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkGETorPOST);` pra ter acesso a variável nome, mas, quando executo recebo os erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

quando tendo depurar:

o erro ocorre na linha `Execute;`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, como você não especificou, vou partir da premissa que você está utilizando JAX-RS no seu Controller.
Quando vc não especifica o tipo de parâmetro, o JAX entende que você quer utilizá-lo como corpo da requisição.

Nesse caso, você deve especificar no seu client, o content-type da requisição, e passar o nome do banco no corpo. Nesse seu caso, tanto "text/plain" quanto "application/json" devem funcionar, já que toda String é um Json válido.

Uma outra possibilidade seria você utilizar o @QueryParam, e passar seu valor como um query parameter. Ficaria mais ou menos assim a url:

```
http://localhost:8080/{seuContexto}/Banco/put/{codigo}?nome={nomeDoSeuBanco}
```